# ObtainContentsRichTextBox() has the wrong return type

Tags: c#, return-type, invokerequired

I am trying to write a method that reads the contents of a richtext box from another thread. Below is the code I have:

```
    /** @delegate */
    private delegate void RichTextBoxObtainContentsEventHandler();

    private string ObtainContentsRichTextBox()
    {

        if (richtxtStatus.InvokeRequired)
        {
            // this means we're on the wrong thread!  
            // use BeginInvoke or Invoke to call back on the 
            // correct thread.
            richtxtStatus.Invoke(
                new RichTextBoxObtainContentsEventHandler(ObtainContentsRichTextBox)
                );
        }

        return richtxtStatus.Text.ToString();

    }
```

However I get the following error message:

'string WindowsFormsApplication1.frmMain.ObtainContentsRichTextBox()' has the wrong return type

I'm sure I am doing something simple wrong but I'm a bit of a C# novice. Can anyone point me as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your delegate is `void`, but you call it with a function that returns `string`? I've not really used delegates before, but that can't be right. Also does the error appear at compile-time or at runtime?

Comment: That seems to have been the problem. Although I'm still facing another problem. I'll update the description above.

Comment: Actually I think I will open a different question for that as its a seperate question. I'm uncertain how I can award you credit for this since you commented though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your delegate is void, but you call it with a function that returns string. That is what causes the problem.

Comment: thanks for your reply, it helped, but how to fix it?